# Role management via Fiori launchpad

Tags: sap-fiori

I am front end developer having no idea about the backend. I've created a report in SAPUI5 which shows the report of a course. every user can see only his report and there are 3 different type of role for using application. for example, an administrator can see all course reports whereas owner can see only his courses. some user can view the only one course.  I've deployed the application in Fiori launchpad. Right now I've not implemented any user-specific detail in the application. My query is that can I access the detail of user in my application who will login via Fiori launchpad. 2dnly How I can configure user into launchpad. so I can assign a specific user to a specific role. Is it possible without back-end configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure roles in the backend.

Users need authorization roles to run the SAP Fiori launchpad (as an end user) and the SAP Fiori launchpad designer (as an administrator). 
When users have these roles, they can access the catalogs and groups assigned to the roles by a role administrator. 
As a role administrator, you assign the necessary authorization roles and adjust them according to your needs.

Role administrators make tile catalogs and groups available on the end user's page by assigning tile catalogs and tile groups
to a PFCG role to which users can be assigned. Users logging on to the launchpad see all assigned groups on their home page, 
and when users open the catalog section, they can access all tiles in the assigned catalogs.

The following documentation might be helpful:

- [Configuring Roles with Launchpad Start Authorizations](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc1c7615ee2f4a699a9272453379006c/7.5.7/en-US/85be3fff35604fa09a1668dd97ef4407.html)
- [Configuring Roles for Tile Catalogs and Groups](https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc1c7615ee2f4a699a9272453379006c/7.5.7/en-US/c9cdf5ac9617457a9be2a00a0cb5aacb.html)
- [SAP Fiori - SAP Fiori launchpad](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Fiori/SAP+Fiori+-+SAP+Fiori+launchpad)

Comment: Can I get launchpad user information in my sapui5? 2ndly what is PFCG ? do I need any backend service (netweaver, ABAP) I've no idea of that things

Comment: PFCG is the transaction for Role Maintenance in the ABAP backend.

How did you implement the 3 different type of roles for your users?
Did you do it all by yourself in UI5?

Do you keep your course data locally without a backend?
Usually the persistent data is kept in the backend and accessed via Odata service.
This also requires roles and authorizations maintained in the backend for your users.

Comment: The following documentation might be useful: [Enable App for Access in SAP Fiori Launchpad](https://help.sap.com/doc/f5116790deab4cb68a14ae7cec5e8a45/2.0%202016-08/en-US/frameset.htm?9f5e03bed125426ab70b1c08c74667f5.html), [SAP Fiori Launchpad](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw751abap/helpdata/en/bd/e12a271f0647e799b338574cda0808/frameset.htm), [User Management and Authorization](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f3e3a9ffe47f4c039ebd1546747288f2/7.51.3.0/en-US/20bc5d521178f55fe10000000a423f68.html)

Comment: Please also see: [UI Content and Authorization Concept](https://help.sap.com/viewer/f3e3a9ffe47f4c039ebd1546747288f2/7.51.3.0/en-US/3c49e1a27806488689b2ad7c67e77291.html) and [SAP Fiori Implementation Information](https://help.sap.com/viewer/p/FIORI_IMPLEMENTATION)

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. The data is in odata format provided by another user. I need to implement  UI. I have access to Launchpad and I've created roles, categories, groups etc. I've no access to the backend. can I manage user control from front-end so the user can see only his specific report? Like I can filter the data via user id or user name after user login

Comment: With no access to the backend, it seems that you have to implement the authorizations all on yourself in the UI.
Using this service “sap.ushell.services.UserInfo” or this service „sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo")” 
as seen here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ushell.services.UserInfo.html,
you should be able to get your UserId, as seen also here:
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3538527
https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3519253
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/12/02/custom-user-image-in-fiori-2.0/

Did you create your roles with PFCG?